# Change Beamer color theme to #009045

Tags: beamer, color

I'm trying to change the color of the following theme:

[Examen Profesional ITAM](https://pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/examen-profesional-itam/xkppkzscmxhc)

I can change the color with the `\usecolortheme{}` command, but I specifically wanted to change it to green (`#009045`) because it's my school's color.

Basically I wanted the theme to follow the same style, just change the green color that is currently already present to the color `#009045`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This beamer theme `ZMBZFMK`, which is defined in a file called `beamerthemeZMBZFMK.sty`, uses a specific `\colortheme` that is loaded using the file `beamercolorthemeZMBZFMK.sty`. And this files  defines the green color used for the boxes and headlines on the frames with `\definecolor{tublue}{RGB}{0,152,103}`.

Thus, you may want to redefine this color directly after having loaded this beamer theme. So, in your preamble, look for the following line:

```
\usetheme{ZMBZFMK}
```

and add this line after it (which overrides the default definition of the color `tublue` which is actually the green you want to change):

```
\definecolor{tublue}{RGB}{0,144,69} % decimal representation of #009045
```

Note that this will not change the color of the logo, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The logo i changed by beamerthemeZMBZFMK.sty to